# ggplot2: Leave one of the margins as default

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)

#default
ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width))+
  geom_point()

#modify margins
ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width))+
  geom_point()+
  theme(plot.margin=grid::unit(c(1,1,1,1),"cm"))
```

Now I am trying to control some margins while others are left as default.

```
#doesn't work
ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width))+
  geom_point()+
  theme(plot.margin=grid::unit(c(1,1,1,NULL),"cm"))
```

Using NA or NULL doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
add_margin = function(...)  grid::convertUnit(theme_get()[["plot.margin"]] + margin(...), "cm")

 ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width))+
   geom_point()+ theme(plot.margin = add_margin(l=2, unit="cm"))
```